# Assign default value of IntEnum inside dataclass object results in variable at same address as other object

Tags: python, enums, default-value

I'm trying to assign a default value to a IntEnum and int inside my dataclass. If i initialize the second variable of the class it results in a reference of the IntEnum and int to the first variable:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from enum import IntEnum

class E_Enum(IntEnum):
    Init = 0,
    First = 1,
    Second = 2


@dataclass
class A():
    a: int = 0
    b: E_Enum = E_Enum.Init

test1 = A()
test2 = A()

print("Int")
print(hex(id(test1.a)))
print(hex(id(test2.a)))

print("Enum")
print(hex(id(test1.b)))
print(hex(id(test2.b)))
```

The output of the above code is:

```
Int
0x7ff9f62a7c20
0x7ff9f62a7c20
Enum
0x24d81972808
0x24d81972808
```

As you see the Enum and Int are located at the exact same memory address. The only way to fix this to assign a new value to the attributes after initializing the class as this:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from enum import IntEnum

class E_Enum(IntEnum):
    Init = 0,
    First = 1,
    Second = 2


@dataclass
class A():
    a: int = 0
    b: E_Enum = E_Enum.Init

test1 = A()
test1.a = 5
test1.b = E_Enum(1)
test2 = A()
test2.a = 10
test2.b = E_Enum(2)

print("Int")
print(hex(id(test1.a)))
print(hex(id(test2.a)))

print("Enum")
print(hex(id(test1.b)))
print(hex(id(test2.b)))
```

This results in:

```
Int
0x7ffa00bc7cc0
0x7ffa00bc7d60
Enum
0x23c8e720588
0x23c8e738888
```

Which are diffrent address for both attributes. Is there a way to to make the variable memory address unique from the initialization step or am i missing something fundamently? Is this expected behaviour and if its is is there any reason for this? The only thing i can think of is memory optimization.

Comment: You seem to be thinking of Python as a lot more C-like than it really is. You're thinking of `id` as if it's a C-like `&` operator, giving addresses of things, and you're thinking of those addresses as the addresses of *variables* when `id` gives ID numbers for *objects*. It might help to read up on [the relationship between objects and variables in Python](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: (On a more syntactical level, you're also making the mistake of C-style comma-separating your enum members. That's not how Python syntax works - you're not supposed to put commas between enum member definitions. If you try that with a regular `Enum` instead of an `IntEnum`, you'll find that the commas cause the corresponding enum values to be 1-element tuples.)

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental thing you are missing is that in Python addresses are meaningless, and `id()` returning an address is a cPython implementation detail (indeed, other Python implementations just start a counter and assign the next value to the next object).

The only thing that `id()` will tell you is if some objects are the exact same object, but the correct way to check that is with `is`:

```
if some_var is None:
    ...
```

Again, as a cPython implementation detail, some small ints and spaceless strings are cached and reused.

`Enum`, on the other hand, does guarantee that each member is unique and constant -- the entire time that your program is running there will only ever be one `E_Enum.Init` object.

The reason you are seeing different ids in your second example is that you are assigning `E_Enum.First` to `test1.b` and `E_Enum.Second` to `test2.b`.